# #debug no longer works in POVray

Tags: povray

From time to time I add `#debug` statement to my POVray scenes, and up till now they worked without problems. This morning I used an `.ini` file to allow me to log the debug statement to a file. Worked fine too.

I moved to another project and debugging no longer works; none of the messages are shown under the messages tab. I tried it again with a log file, but while the file gets created it remains empty.

The last thing I tried was adding `debug.inc` to my include statements and adding `Set_Debug(true)`. Still no avail.

Any ideas how I can get debugging back?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a line break before and after the debug text ? I had a similar problem and doing something like this fixed it :

```
#debug concat("\n", "debug text", "\n")
```